# Throttle concurrent HTTP requests from Spark executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

I want to do some Http requests from inside a Spark job to a rate limited API. In order to keep track of the number of concurrent requests in a **non-distributed** system (in Scala), following works:

- a throttling actor which maintains a semaphore (counter) which increments when the request starts and decrements when the request completes. Although `Akka` is distributed, there are issues to (de)serialize the `actorSystem` in a distributed Spark context.
- using parallel streams with fs2: https://fs2.io/concurrency-primitives.html => cannot be distributed.
- I suppose I could also just `collect` the dataframes to the Spark `driver` and handle throttling there with one of above options, but I would like to keep this distributed.

How are such things typically handled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't try to synchronise requests across Spark executors/partitions. This is totally against Spark concurrency model.

Instead, for example, divide the global rate limit R by Executors * Cores and use `mapPatitions` to send requests 
from each partition within its R/(e*c) rate limit.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by `use mapPatitions to send requests from each partition within its R/(e*c) rate limit.`?

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi Suppose your global rate limit is 1000 req/sec, and you have 5 executors with 2 cores each. This means you have 10 tasks running in parallel and the "local" rate limit is then 1000/10=100, so every task needs to make sure not to exceed 100 requests per second.