# How to throttle Spark API calls?

Tags: rest, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+
|               user_id                |    city    | 
+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883 | Toronto    |
| e2ddv22d-4132-c211-4425-9933aa8de454 | Washington |
+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

I need to transform a user_id to another id via API call. So what I did is I used a Spark UDF like below:

```
spark.udf.register("my_udf", (user_id: String) = {
    makeApiCall(user_id);
})
```

And then call the UDF so that it will transform it.

```
SELECT my_udf(user_id) FROM my_table;
```

This works, however I'll be needing to throttle the API calls since I could have a large dataset. Unfortunately, I don't have an option to batch the user_ids since API call accepts only one user_id per request. So what I thought to do is to throttle (e.g. send x number of request per minute)

Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: Use streaming. Reduce stream window so less data will be processed at a time

Comment: You really shouldn't use UDF for making external api calls

Comment: @Salim can you provide an example where I can use streaming to rate limit the map calls?

Comment: @shay__ what do you suggest?

Comment: see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880255/throttle-concurrent-http-requests-from-spark-executors/58881627#58881627